# How to input '#' in Emacs with UK keyboard on Mac OS X?

Tags: keystrokes

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 in Mac OS X.

Recently I had to input `£` frequently so I changed my input source from U.S. to British. With British keyboard, <kbd>Option+3</kbd> will yield `#` in other editors, however, this doesn't work in Emacs since `M` is special keystroke in Emacs.

How can I insert `#` in Emacs in Mac OS X with Brithsh keyboard?

Comment: I use my left for meta and my right for stock Apple stuff:  `(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta) (setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)`  There are other methods, but I'll leave those for other forum participants to chime in.

Comment: @lawlist I think your comment can be an answer.

Comment: Yet another possibility is to use [ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) or [karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap your keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other methods than the one mentioned in this answer, but I personally prefer the best of both worlds -- i.e., I use the left alt/option key as meta, and I use the right alt/option key for stock Apple stuff -- e.g., special characters like the ones mentioned by the original poster:

```lisp
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
```

Comment: I googled and found other ways like override `M-3` to insert £, however, I prefer to the method you described.

Comment: One of the most popular methods is with `C-x 8`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unibyte-Mode.html  -- type `C-x 8 C-h` to see available characters.